# Why is gets() more dangerous than scanf()?

Tags: c

It seems to me that both have the potential to overflow the buffer. Yet I'm adviced to never use gets() but still encouraged to use scanf().

Is it just because of the formatting arguments allowed in scanf() or is there any other reason?

Comment: One, because of the escape characters, `gets()` doesn't filter endline

Comment: Probably because while gets() is hopeless, with scanf you can avoid buffer overflows if you go through the pain of limiting input length **every** **single** **time**

Comment: IIRC `gets()` doesn't give you the line if there is no '\n', but `EOF` instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `gets` function is not protected against buffer overflows.

With the `scanf` format string you can define the maximal length of the string to read from standard input and store in the given memory buffer. For example with `scanf("%10s\n", str);` a maximum of 10 characters will be read. The `str` buffer should be of 11 bytes to store the NULL terminating character.

Performance wise, if you only use `scanf` to workaround the buffer overflow issues of `gets`, prefer using the `fgets` function instead.

Comment: Doing some research i also found that: 

scanf() will not only allow
you to enter more than one field,
but it also allows you to enter
**structured** data including the
ability to specify what characters
appear between fields.

So i think that's also interesting to keep in mind.

Source: Head First C, Daivid & Dawn Griffiths.

Comment: You are right, `scanf` and `gets` (or `fgets`) does not cover the same use cases. You use `fgets` to read one line from input stream. You use `scanf` for parsing data from input stream. This said you can use `scanf` to read one line from input stream as you would do with a `fgets` but it will result in a performance loss.

Answer (score 2):

Because you can input more characters than size of the buffer and gets() will happily allow it. Moreover, gets() has been deprecated (in C11). So the comparison with scanf() is no longer valid. Besides scanf() has its own problems when dealing with unformatted data.

So a better option would be [fgets()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) and then process it as per your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no way to prevent buffer overflow. fgets is safer as the maximum buffer length is specified.

Comment: The question is really about `gets` vs. `scanf`.

Answer (score 1):

With `gets` it is not possible to prevent a buffer overflow in case of malformed input. `scanf` allows the control over amount of data read.

[How to prevent scanf causing a buffer overflow in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621394/how-to-prevent-scanf-causing-a-buffer-overflow-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

> still encouraged to use scanf().

A quick Google search for "scanf security" turns up ~212k results. The first is [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf_format_string#Security), which states that

> uses of `%s` placeholders without length specifiers are inherently insecure and exploitable for buffer overflows.

So there's enough info about `scanf` security on the web. The difference with `gets` is that `scanf` has secure uses, while using `gets` is practically always a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

The nominal task of gets() is to read in a string from a stream. The caller tells it where to put the incoming characters. But gets() does not check the buffer space. If the caller provides a pointer to the stack, and more input than buffer space, gets() will overwrite the stack. Most systems are vulnerable to overwriting an existing entry in the middle of the stack with something bigger, that also overwrites neighboring entries. A malefactor can amend the return address in the procedure activation record on the stack by stashing the right binary patterns in the argument string. This will divert the flow of execution not back to where it came from, but to a special instruction sequence that calls execv() to replace the running image with a shell. This shell can issue commands to drag across a copy of the virus to the system. So gets() is not safe.

Comment: This doesn't explain why `scanf` is any safer.